# 'Invalid redirect_uri' while login with facebook account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I was using [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-use-omniauth-to-authenticate-your-users/) to add facebook login to my app.  But when I clicked 'login with facebook' link I get error in the browser:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: \u0414\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0439 URL \u043d\u0435 \u0434\u043e\u043f\u0443\u0441\u043a\u0430\u0435\u0442\u0441\u044f \u043a\u043e\u043d\u0444\u0438\u0433\u0443\u0440\u0430\u0446\u0438\u0435\u0439 \u043f\u0440\u0438\u043b\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }
}
```

Here is URL in the browser in the redirect moment:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=267752453309765&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email%2Coffline_access

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't redirect to localhost, you need to redirect to a location that Facebook can actually reach like a public IP address.

Comment: You can indeed redirect to localhost: just set your Site URL to "http://localhost:3000/" and your Site Domain to "localhost" in your Facebook app settings.

Comment: You can redirect to localhost, because this is all from the browser's point of view and not an external host

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your Facebook app's Site URL and Site Domain?  What do you get when you set your Site URL to http://localhost:3000/ and your Site Domain to localhost in your app settings?